# Full height background color with bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I have a page and I am using bootstrap for styling.I am trying to force the `background-color` to be full height, but because my content doesn't fill, it leaves a large white space at bottom.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #f5faff; font-family: Segoe UI; padding: 0;">
    <div style="background-color: #0070c0; min-height:100px;">
        <h1 style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 24px; padding-left:20px; padding-top: 30px;">Problem Phase Worksheet:</h1>
    </div>
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" style="padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 20px;">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <span style="color: #0070c0; font-size: 18px;">Inputs</span>
            </div>          
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="criteria" style="font-size: 14px;">Criteria:  <a href="#criteriaModal" data-toggle="modal"><span style="color: #afabab;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></a></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="criteria" ng-model="criteria" style="font-size: 14px;" placeholder="(e.g. more than 80%)">
            </div>              
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="customer" style="font-size: 14px;">Customer:  <a href="#criteriaModal" data-toggle="modal"><span style="color: #afabab;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></a></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="customer" ng-model="customer" style="font-size: 14px;" placeholder="(e.g. enterprise system admins)">
                <!-- <p style="font-size: 12px;">(e.g. Infrastructure admins, network engineer, etc..)</p>   -->      
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="task" style="font-size: 14px;">Job to be Done:  <a href="#criteriaModal" data-toggle="modal"><span style="color: #afabab;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></a></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="task" ng-model="task" style="font-size: 14px;" placeholder="(e.g. keeping servers up to date)">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="problem" style="font-size: 14px;">Problem:  <a href="#criteriaModal" data-toggle="modal"><span style="color: #afabab;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></a></label>          
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="problem" ng-model="problem" style="font-size: 14px;" placeholder="(e.g. it takes to long (24+ hours) )">
            </div>  
        </div>  
        <!-- criteriaModal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="criteriaModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="criteriaModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                            &times;
                        </button>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean consequat odio vel fermentum faucibus. Phasellus vestibulum, justo sed vestibulum bibendum, risus mauris congue nisi, et iaculis ipsum nisl a turpis. Vivamus et purus diam. Proin sagittis nisl eu porttitor posuere. Phasellus feugiat nec elit et hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque blandit a quam eget malesuada. Cras lobortis augue nibh, a feugiat justo consequat ac. In sit amet pulvinar massa. In maximus, justo eget elementum laoreet, lacus nunc molestie lectus, at congue neque nisl quis est. Nam non laoreet mauris. Phasellus non ullamcorper libero. Duis dapibus ornare arcu in fringilla. Curabitur molestie ex eu nunc ultricies, id pharetra nisl semper.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="button" class="naviaBtn naviaBlue" data-dismiss="modal" value="okay">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal -->        
        <div class="col-md-6">   
            <div> 
                <span style="color: #0070c0; font-size: 18px;">Examples</span>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right; font-size: 18px;">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>  Email
                </button>
            </div>              
            <div style="background-color: #ffffff; padding: 15px; margin-top: 20px; border: 1px solid #ccc;">       
                <div>
                    <p style="font-size: 12px; color: #afabab;">HYPOTHESIS:</p>
                    <p style="font-size: 14px;">We believe that <span>{{ criteria || '[criteria]' }}</span> of <span>{{ (customer != null) ? customer : '[customer]' }}</span> are most frustrated about <span>{{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }}</span> because <span>{{ problem || '[problem]' }}</span>.</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p style="font-size: 12px; color: #afabab;">CUSTOMER SCREENING CRITERIA:</p>
                    <p style="font-size: 14px;">We are looking for <span>{{ (customer != null) ? customer : '[customer]' }}</span> who are regularly involved in <span>{{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }}</span>.</p>
                </div> 
                <div>
                    <p style="font-size: 12px; color: #afabab;">SCREENER:</p>
                    <p style="font-size: 14px;">How often do you <span>{{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }}</span> in your daily job?</p>
                </div>    
                <div>
                    <p style="font-size: 12px; color: #afabab;">CUSTOMER INTERVIEW QUESTIONS:</p>
                    <p style="font-size: 14px;">Tell me about the last time when you were <span>{{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }}</span>?</p>
                    <p style="font-size: 14px;">What are the major challenges with <span>{{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }}</span>?</p>
                    <p style="font-size: 14px;">On a scale of 0-10, how frustrating are these problems? Why?</p>            
                    <p style="font-size: 14px;">If you could wave a magic wand and be able to do anything about <span>{{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }}</span> in your daily job, what would it be?</p>
                </div>  
            </div>          
        </div>                         
    </form>
</div>
```

And looks like:

[image]

What am I doing wrong on this? I have tried using the `row-fluid` class on parent div and all, but no luck. Thoughts?

Comment: Give your full code.

Comment: You can make height:100%; to your container-fluid class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

container-fluid does not set the div to be full height

try setting the background-color directly to

```
<body>
```

instead, if your design allows it

Comment: Thanks. I know it was something silly and simple I was over looking. I am actually injecting my views via angular and forgot that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a background throughout the page entirely:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

body {
  background-color: #f5faff;
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div style="background-color: #0070c0; min-height:100px;">
        <h1 style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 24px; padding-left:20px; padding-top: 30px;">Problem Phase Worksheet:</h1>
    </div>
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" style="padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 20px;">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <span style="color: #0070c0; font-size: 18px;">Inputs</span>
            </div>          
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="criteria">Criteria:  <a href="#criteriaModal" data-toggle="modal"><span style="color: #afabab;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></a></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="criteria" ng-model="criteria" placeholder="(e.g. more than 80%)">
            </div>              
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="customer">Customer:  <a href="#criteriaModal" data-toggle="modal"><span style="color: #afabab;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></a></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="customer" ng-model="customer" placeholder="(e.g. enterprise system admins)">
                <!-- <p style="font-size: 12px;">(e.g. Infrastructure admins, network engineer, etc..)</p>   -->      
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="task">Job to be Done:  <a href="#criteriaModal" data-toggle="modal"><span style="color: #afabab;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></a></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="task" ng-model="task" placeholder="(e.g. keeping servers up to date)">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="problem">Problem:  <a href="#criteriaModal" data-toggle="modal"><span style="color: #afabab;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></a></label>          
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="problem" ng-model="problem" placeholder="(e.g. it takes to long (24+ hours) )">
            </div>  
        </div>  
        <!-- criteriaModal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="criteriaModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="criteriaModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                            &times;
                        </button>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean consequat odio vel fermentum faucibus. Phasellus vestibulum, justo sed vestibulum bibendum, risus mauris congue nisi, et iaculis ipsum nisl a turpis. Vivamus et purus diam. Proin sagittis nisl eu porttitor posuere. Phasellus feugiat nec elit et hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque blandit a quam eget malesuada. Cras lobortis augue nibh, a feugiat justo consequat ac. In sit amet pulvinar massa. In maximus, justo eget elementum laoreet, lacus nunc molestie lectus, at congue neque nisl quis est. Nam non laoreet mauris. Phasellus non ullamcorper libero. Duis dapibus ornare arcu in fringilla. Curabitur molestie ex eu nunc ultricies, id pharetra nisl semper.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="button" class="naviaBtn naviaBlue" data-dismiss="modal" value="okay">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal -->        
        <div class="col-md-6">   
            <div> 
                <span style="color: #0070c0; font-size: 18px;">Examples</span>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right; font-size: 18px;">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>  Email
                </button>
            </div>              
            <div style="background-color: #ffffff; padding: 15px; margin-top: 20px; border: 1px solid #ccc;">       
                <div>
                    <p style="font-size: 12px; color: #afabab;">HYPOTHESIS:</p>
                    <p>We believe that <span>{{ criteria || '[criteria]' }}</span> of <span>{{ (customer != null) ? customer : '[customer]' }}</span> are most frustrated about <span>{{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }}</span> because <span>{{ problem || '[problem]' }}</span>.</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p style="font-size: 12px; color: #afabab;">CUSTOMER SCREENING CRITERIA:</p>
                    <p>We are looking for <span>{{ (customer != null) ? customer : '[customer]' }}</span> who are regularly involved in <span>{{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }}</span>.</p>
                </div> 
                <div>
                    <p style="font-size: 12px; color: #afabab;">SCREENER:</p>
                    <p>How often do you <span>{{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }}</span> in your daily job?</p>
                </div>    
                <div>
                    <p style="font-size: 12px; color: #afabab;">CUSTOMER INTERVIEW QUESTIONS:</p>
                    <p>Tell me about the last time when you were <span>{{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }}</span>?</p>
                    <p>What are the major challenges with <span>{{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }}</span>?</p>
                    <p>On a scale of 0-10, how frustrating are these problems? Why?</p>            
                    <p>If you could wave a magic wand and be able to do anything about <span>{{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }}</span> in your daily job, what would it be?</p>
                </div>  
            </div>          
        </div>                         
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `<head>` tag of your page, write the Internal style for body tag.

`body{ background-color: green; }`

Now you page will have full height background color.

**Edit:**
Here is the code for inline style.

```
<head>
//Link to the bootstrap.css file here.
//internal style for the page.
<style>
    body { background-color:green;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

</body>
```

Comment: In head tag internal style for body tag? How can you write internal style for body in head tag